# Case-insensitive string comparison with I18N text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to compare strings case insensitively.

The obvious answer would be to use toUpperCase(), 
but when dealing with turkish characters, toUpperCase() changes some of those unique characters into something else.

Help.

FYI i'm comparing League of Legends usernames

Comment: /someString/i.test(someVariable)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this custom function to uppercase turkish characters

```
String.prototype.turkishToUpper = function () {
        var string = this;
        var letters = { "i": "İ", "ş": "Ş", "ğ": "Ğ", "ü": "Ü", "ö": "Ö", "ç": "Ç", "ı": "I" };
        string = string.replace(/(([iışğüçö]))/g, function (letter) { return letters[letter]; })
        return string.toUpperCase();
    }

var turkishUpperCase = yourWord.turkishToUpper()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below functions

```
String.prototype.turkishToUpper = function(){
   var string = this;
   var letters = { "i": "İ", "ş": "Ş", "ğ": "Ğ", "ü": "Ü", "ö": "Ö", "ç": "Ç", "ı": "I" };
   string = string.replace(/(([iışğüçö]))+/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; })
   return string.toUpperCase();
}

String.prototype.turkishToLower = function(){
   var string = this;
   var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç" };
   string = string.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖ]))+/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; })
   return string.toLowerCase();
}
```